# Solving this PDE with exponential functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This question is an extension of this thread :

[How to solve this homogeneous partial differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139918/how-to-solve-this-homogeneous-partial-differential-equation/4140123#4140123)

I'm trying to find a way to solve this equation:

$$ \ddot\rho \lambda  + \rho \lambda’’  + e^\rho e^\lambda p - e^{2\rho} e^{2\lambda}  q =0 $$

Or

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial t^2} \lambda + \rho \frac{\partial^2 \lambda}{\partial y^2}  + e^\rho e^\lambda p - e^{2\rho} e^{2\lambda}  q =0 $$

P and q are constants. Here a function $\sigma$ depends on both variables t and $y$. So that I have defined:

$$ \sigma(t, y) = \rho(t) \lambda(y) $$

The first thing I have tried to make separation of variables by multiplying by $\frac{1}{\rho \lambda}$, but this does not work due to the exponential functions.

So please let me know if anyone knows how to solve this PDE.

Thanks

Comment: You have $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu = \partial_{tt} + \partial_{yy}$. Is this a typo or are you working in Euclidean space? Your equation looks similar to the sine Gordon equation. Is there any reason to believe that there is a 'nice' exact solution here? Are you looking for the general solution or eg. trying to show the existence of soliton solutions?

Comment: No I'm not working in the Euclidean space. Take the function $ \sigma$ simply depends on two variables.